# File ios problems - unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, ios, file, unrecognized-selector

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    textBox = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 40)];
    [textBox setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:textBox];
    [textBox release];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(saveText) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];


    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *dataFile;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Identify the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSLog(@"PATH--->  %@",dirPaths);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the data file
    dataFile = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"datafile.dat"];

    // Check if the file already exists
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: dataFile])
    {
        // Read file contents and display in textBox
        NSData *databuffer;
        databuffer = [filemgr contentsAtPath: dataFile];

        NSString *datastring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: databuffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        textBox.text = datastring;
        [datastring release];
    }

    [filemgr release];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; 
    return YES; 
}

- (void)saveText:(id)sender
{ 
    NSLog(@"Text saved");
}
```

If I try executing this I am getting an error saying

> "2013-02-18 12:43:46.194 FileExample[1475:207] -[FileExampleViewController saveText]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x682e730"

I am new to iOS and am not able to identify or understand or debut this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your this line

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(saveText) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

with this

```
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(saveText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

OR

do this

```
- (void)saveText // removed  " :(id)sender "
 { 
    NSLog(@"Text saved");
 }
```

Comment: Also please make sure that the method **saveText** is declared in **FileExampleViewController.h** file

Comment: @Yogi That has no effect in this case.  `@selector` doesn't do any header checking, it just calls the method assuming it exists.